# How to iterate through rows of a dynamic table using selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to iterate through the rows of a dynamic table, that varies in size depending on a term search (15 rows in the example). I need to use XPATHs whenever I can. I am able to find the table using

```
table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table")
```

and I get this as a result

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c2751dcd31f53b537b734f9877de4db", element="f623cddd-98fe-4ba1-b72f-6e0d717e7666")
```

The table has multiple rows, each with the  tag. Inside each row, I find 6 columns with the  tag. On the second column of each row, there's a button. How can I iterate through the table and click on each row's button? Here is an image of what I'm seeing (I'm new to selenium and webscraping in general):
[image]

I've tried to use a range that counts the number of rows of the table but it hasn't worked. I also tried looking for elements with the class "blue--text v-btn v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default" which appear to be the class of the buttons I need to click on, with no success.

Comment: What does clicking the buttons do? Can you share the site?

Comment: And have you tried with *buttons* of that class? Like with XPath `//button[@type="button"][@class="blue--text v-btn v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default"]`? That should have worked....but without trying on the site itself, I can't check if there's something else you need to do

Comment: Are there more table elements in the page?